# model function call in blade view laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

### My model code

how we can call this function in blade.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class BasicModel extends Model
{
     public static function get_product_count($id){
        $query = "select COUNT(sub_id) AS count FROM products WHERE products.sub_id = $id";
        print_r($query);
        return $query->row_array();
    }

}
```

### My view.blade.php code

count in foreach loop or show in all category

```
@foreach ($r as $row)
         <li class="grid-item type-rent">
         <div class="property-block"> 
           <a href="#" class="property-featured-image"> <img src="{{ URL::to('/template/images/background-images/sub-category-images/' .$row->sub_cat_images. '')}}" alt=""> <!-- <span class="images-count"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i> 2</span> <span class="badges">Rent</span> --> </a>
              <div class="property-info">
                 <h4><a href="#">{{ ucwords(substr($row->sub_cat_name, 0, 22)) }}</a></h4>
                 <span class="location">NYC</span>
                   <div class="price"><strong>Items</strong><span>

                              <!-- start count code from here --> 
                              $data = $this->BasicModel->count {{ ($row->sub_id) }}
                              echo $data['count'];
                             </span></div>
                  </div>

               <!-- <div class="property-amenities clearfix"> <span class="area"><strong>5000</strong>Area</span> <span class="baths"><strong>3</strong>Baths</span> <span class="beds"><strong>3</strong>Beds</span> <span class="parking"><strong>1</strong>Parking</span> </div> -->
         </div>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

### My BasicController Code

```
public function grid(Request $request, $id)
    {  
        if ($id == 1) {
            $r = DB::table('sub_category')->select('*')->where('cat_id', $id)
            ->where('sub_status', '1')->orderBy('sub_id', 'asc')->get();

            $name = DB::table('category')->where('cat_id', $id)->get();

           return view('buy-and-sell/grid', compact('r','name','count'));
        }
```

### image for your help

[image: for help]

### image for your help

problem in this image please solve the problem
[image: for help]

Comment: simple php query use in codeigniter but not apply in laravel

Comment: you used it the wrong way - that's why it's not simple at all. in Laravel term, `Model` only defines table's relationship, not their query. read the [docs more](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent) and stop telling people CI is better than Laravel - i didn't join stackoverflow to start a holy war. also, your view looked not *natural* in Laravel, we had [`Blade`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade) use it well, and feel the benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although its no good Practice Accessing the DB in Blade (better do this in the controller and pass the data) you can do:

```
 <div class="price"><strong>Products</strong>
<span>
    {{ BasicModel::where('sub_id', $row->sub_id)->count() }}
  </span>
</div>
```

Its not tested, but have a look at the Eloquent docs, the count() method is explained there.

Update: I am not shure if laravel will find the class BasicModel (I never would access Models directly in blade, as stated do this in the controller and pass the data.) So maybe you need to write it with the full Namespace most likely `{{ \App\BasicModel::where() }}`.

Comment: how we can solve this problem. You told me any proccess

Comment: {{ APP\BasicModel::get_product_count('sub_id', $row->sub_id)->count() }}

Comment: 1.) Test this in the blade template: {{App\BasicModel::all() }}. If all data is printed, fine, then you have access to the BasicModell working. Then do this 2.) {{ BasicModel::where('sub_id', $row->sub_id)->count() }}. What you wrote in your comment will not work. You can not call ->count() on your own methond get_product_count(). You can only call count it on some laravel methods of BasicModel that return an Elqoeunt Query object.